# Google Drive not showing any folders?

Tags: google-drive

When I go to Google Drive, all I'm presented with is the following screen:

[image]

None of my folders are showing up. They are still there, because in the bottom of the left sidebar there is still '1.4 TB used' visible, and if I go to the starred list, my starred files are still present, downloadable, etc. Is there a way to get my top level folders to appear in My Drive? When I click the 'My Drive' in the sidebar, there is no drop down option. The icon just turns blue as in the picture.

Comment: Try using the private or safe navigation mode of your web browser with all the extensions disabled. If that solves the problem then the cause is related to your browser otherwise it could be on the Google's side and if you are using a G Suite account ask your account administrator to submit a support ticket to Google.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me before and this is what my IT admin told me to verify:

1. If you have multiple Google accounts, make sure you're on the right one.
2. If this is a work account, your IT admin might ask you whether you've tried viewing this in a different browser. Copy/paste into a different browser to see whether it's still borked.

GSuite occasionally has issues and when they do, people can't work. Time for a well-deserved break... and then try reloading later.